# Why my IE11 F12 Developer Tools couldn't "Pin"?

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

When I use IE10, everything is fine. But IE11, pin button and "Ctrl+P" couldn't work.
My system is Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit with SP1.

Answer (score 6):

Change the `tabprocgrowth` to be 1 :

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"TabProcGrowth"="1"
```

Comment: Try click CTRL+P